# How to write bytebuddy code for private HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> hm;?

Tags: java, hashmap, private, hashset, byte-buddy

If I write bytebuddy code

`.defineProperty("hm",TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(HashMap.class, String.class, HashSet.class).build())`

like this ,Then result is 
`private HashMap<String, HashSet> hm;`

but my requirement is 
`private HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> hm;`

Answer (score 0):

The builder accepts Byte Buddy's `TypeDefinition`s just as much as type literals so you can simply nest the built types:

```
TypeDescription.Generic type = TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
  TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.of(HashMap.class),
  TypeDescription.Generic.Sort.describe(String.class),
  TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(HashSet.class, String.class).build()
).build();
```